# Cant use Http service but can import it in Angular 2

Tags: http, angular, import

[image]

I'm able to import the Http Service to my app but not use because thi errors appears in the console... How can I solve it ?

Comment: Look to angular-cli or similar it would easier for you to start

Comment: thankx for anwering man... what happens is that I'm under the pluralsight platform with the course angular 2 play by play with john papa and ward bell and I followed exactly what they say and it didnt worked... weird though... think I'll do that ! :D

Comment: This is common problem, with angular starters. Angular-cli simplify and hide many things you dont need on the beginning. So you just start writing your app instead of wasting time on figuring our why its not working

Comment: you might have misconfigured your systemjs file. Have a look at this configuration:
https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/src/systemjs.config.js
 Or you could have a look at this quickstart to get started without issues